# Get scala custom exception to show custom details when thrown

Tags: scala

How can I have my custom exceptions include a text message when thrown?
This code snippet demonstrates a wishful intent:

```
case class MyException(errorText: String) extends Exception 

object app extends App {
 throw MyException("How can this be printed along the stack trace?")
}
```

But running in sbt, the custom text is not shown.
What might be the idiomatic way to accomplish that?

Of course I could generically catch any exception and print its details from that catch code, but that would be a little tedious.

Comment: Try this: `case class MyException(errorText: String) extends Exception(errorText)`

Comment: Right! of course! you can make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case class MyException(errorText: String) extends Exception(errorText)
```

Technically speaking this is just [passing a parameter to the superclass constructor](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s12.html), the superclass being java's `Exception` in this case.

Comment: The link is too wordy for this simple concept though. Care to edit this?

Comment: I think it is better to say this question is duplicate of many other questions on SO where you can find much more details. Just search for  *scala constructor case superclass* and things like that.

Comment: Okay I fixed it myself.